# Using box-api in an ARC project?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, box-api

How can I use the box-api in a project using ARC?
I copied the SDK folder to my project and added them, but I can't build my project since it uses ARC.

Comment: Can you share a little more detail? Which SDK are you referring to?

Can you also disambiguate ARC? What do you mean by "uses ARC." Is that a library?

Comment: I'm using the box-api (https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk), copied the SDKFiles folder as readme said. ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) removes the need of manual memory management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable ARC for these files:

1. Go to **Your Project** > **Your Target** > **Build Phases**
2. Select all Box files, press **Enter** and insert "**-fno-objc-arc**" without quotas
3. Clean and Build! ;)

[image]